mysterious linux drive/folder which appears mounted on Windows 11
I have a mysterious drive/folder which appears mounted on Windows 11, called simply 'Linux', which I cannot unmount or otherwise get rid of. It's empty, and there do not seem to be any options for its removal. For some context, while I am not 100% sure when it first appeared, I suspect that it happened when I tried to connect an old Kindle to my PC a while back. I could not connect the Kindle for some reason (I assumed because it was so old), and it's my belief that this 'Linux' drive was the Kindle, mounted incorrectly, or in an incomplete state to the OS. However, I just want to get rid of it, and I don't like how it seems to be untouchable. I have of course searched for a solution to this, but have not found any which deal with this particular scenario. Any suggestions much appreciated.enter image description here

You have WSL installed.  If you don't want it to be installed you can uninstall it. [Edit] your question to include which Windows 11 build you are using in the rare chance this is directly linked to the fact you are running an Windows Insider Preview build.

@Ramhound You just beat me to it. I was about to say the same thing. WSL adds this location to the File Explorer side-bar.
